# User unable to login when base currency change

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency

Can't login after changing the base currency, i have registered a customer when base currency USD. And after i changer the base currency to EURO i cant login with that customer account, its keeps loading but nothing comes. After a while it throws an error on "memory exhausted". But the same user can login when the base currency is USD. I've looked into the exception and system log files as well. No clue as to what is causing this issue.

Basically we are trying to implement Currency switcher, it works well for guest users. But doesn't work when the user is trying to login and the current currency does not match to the currency at the time of user registration.

FYI : magento version is 1.9.2 CE

Comment: Can you post any custom code you've added? This sounds like an error in an extension...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/. This is the link that I followed to get the currency switched on my site. Currently I've disabled this, but the problem still exists. That is the user is unable to login when the base currency is changed. I am new to magento, not sure if I am doing something wrong.